# WooCommerce - new order email hook

Tags: plugins, php

I'd like to sent new order email to another email address. But that email address isn't constant. It is depends of product - I am keeping it in post meta (customers can buy only one item per order).

Is there a hook where would I can programmatically send this e-mail to another e-mail address than only this addresses in WooCommerce configuration?

Answer (score 2):

A list of all the WooCommerce hooks can be found [here](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html).  The way I understand it, e-mail sending is handled by way of the [`WC_Email`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Email.html) class by way of the [`->send()`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Email.html#method_send) method.  According to [the code](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-emails-class-wc-email.html#source-view.654), it looks like the `woocommerce_mail_callback_params` hook might be for what you are looking.